# Diagramming tool to depict objects

Tags: uml, modeling, class-diagram, object-diagram

I wanted to know what tools (preferably free) can be used to layout a collection of objects and their relationship - simple relationship like members referring each other, inheritance, attributes et.al. I would prefer a tool with which I can create and update the diagram as quickly as possible.

I'm not familiar with UML, but it's probably what I'm asking about.

Answer (score 3):

[Mock4U](http://blog.rainer.eschen.name/mock4u/)

[alt text http://typo3.webetiser.com/fileadmin/sites/RainerEschen/downloads/mock4u/class-diagram.png](http://typo3.webetiser.com/fileadmin/sites/RainerEschen/downloads/mock4u/class-diagram.png)

Comment: Seems gratuitously sketchy.  Great for UI mockups, but I'm not so sure about class diagrams.

Comment: I prefer the sketch styling because developers are less likely to think the design is set in stone. It is a small psychological thing, but I swear when I show viso diagrams to people they think they have to implement it to a T.

Comment: Sorry, what's this post about? I can only download a PNG and two other BMML files. What are those meant for?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this page](http://alternativeto.net/desktop/microsoft-visio/) on AlternativeTo, there's a lot of different options listed. Among them:

- [Microsoft Visio](http://office.microsoft.com/visio/)
- [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/)
- [Dia](http://live.gnome.org/Dia)
- [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/applications/omnigraffle)
- [OpenOffice Draw](http://www.openoffice.org/product/draw.html)
- [Creately](http://creately.com/)
- etc.

Comment: MS Visio is rather expensive, considering that for UML design you don't need that many features and there are several Open Source/Free Software alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

**Umlet**

http://www.umlet.com/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/) is a good free tool.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You also have [StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/), wich is open source and similar to [Rational Rose](http://www.ibm.com/software/rational), only a bit simpler.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I really like [Dia](http://www.gnome.org/projects/dia/). It even has a [Portable edition](http://portableapps.com/node/16648)!

It's small, fast, cross OS, simple to use, and has a lot of built in elements (specially for UML modelling).

The only problem I can foresee for you is that it follows The GIMP's GUI design (separated window for the toolbox). I happen to like it, but many people hate it.

Keep in mind that this screenshots are quite old:

[image]
<sub>(source: [gnome.org](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/images/workspac.gif))</sub>  !

It also can be [scripted with Python](http://www.gnome.org/projects/dia/python.html).